# Ansible Python API connect with a different port

Tags: python, ansible

How can I specified a different port than 22.
I tried without success :

```
inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager, host_list=[192.168.0.1:3300])
```

and

```
Options = namedtuple('Options',['remote_port'])    
options = Options(remote_port=3300)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by reading the source code:

```
 play_source = dict(
     name="Ansible Play",
     hosts=host_list,
     gather_facts='no',
     port=222,
     tasks=[dict(action=dict(module='command', args=dict(cmd='/usr/bin/uptime')))]
 )
 play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)
```